# Business category in domain name

Tags: seo, domains, local-seo

I have client for a website. He would like to have a domain name that includes his name and the type of business he is running. This client is a freelancer and his registered name is "hisname" for this example. The type of company is "gartenbau" (gardener in german). He would like to pick one of this combinations:

```
hisname-gartenbau.de
hisnamegartenbau.de
gartenbau-hisname.de
gartenbauhisname.de
```

However, in my opinion all of these names seem ugly to me:

- Domain names without hyphen seem unreadable
- Domain names with hyphen are readable, but more difficult to type.
- All combinations are horrible long

`hisname.de` is still available. This would be short and sweet and represents his registered trade name. However, the client thinks that including the business type would be better for SEO. My counter opinion would be that he can use the word "garternbau" in the page title and content. It would achieve the same.

So my question, would it really matter to include "gartenbau" in the domain name?

I would like to note that I'm not in Germany myself and I'm not aware of any cultural disposition regarding domain names.

Answer (score 2):

My favourites would be these two:

- hisname-gartenbau.de
- gartenbau-hisname.de

The time of exact match domains is gone. And, the domain name, like the business name, should be brandable. From this point of view, the better choice would be something like gartenriese-gartenbau.de. But, on domain names selected by you is nothing bad. Only the name i personally wouldn't take - think, how many of his future clients search his name? I think - nobody, or very few. It is the important consideration: what would better/easier become brand? His name or something like Gartenriese?

Answer (score 1):

If the domain `hisname.de` is available, I think you should go for that.

The Business name can be displayed on the meta-title(visible on the Search result Page) for the homepage and the page can be optimised to rank for the keywords referring to his business name i.e `gartenbau`.

Moreover, this URL is easy to read, remember and type. So when people refer the website to someone else, that person can find the website with ease.

The problem with a hyphenated domain name is that it might be missed while sharing the domain orally.

The best example I would like to cite is of Neil Patel.

Home Page Title: Neil Patel: Helping You Succeed Through Online Marketing!
URL https://neilpatel.com.

He might have gone ahead with neilpatel-digitalmarketing.com but that would have been a worse domain.

His domain name is easy to remember, easy to search and if I search for it, I can see his business in the Page Title.